# jquery / change file in file system and reload it

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-callback

I don't understand,

I have a script in an application who should change an image and re upload it in a render div.

Upload is correct. In file system, file is correctly updated and kept the same name.

But in my render, the "old" file is loaded.

I thought it was a problem of "writing" but I've tried with a timeout but doesn't work ...

This is the "regenerate div" function :

```
var generateIconSetRender = function(icon) {

setTimeout(function() {

    $.Callbacks()
        .add([
            $('#iconset_render').empty(),
            function() {
                var iconSetArray = JSON.parse($('#iconset_array').val());

                for (var i in iconSetArray) {
                    $('#iconset_render').append('<div class="icon"><img src="/tmp/' + iconSetArray[i] + '" /></div>');
                }
            }
        ]).fire();
    console.log('regenerate');
}, 3000);
};
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Potentially a caching issue. Add `?_=' + Date.now()` to the end of your image source and try it again (i.e. `"/tmp/' + iconSetArray[i] + '?_=' + Date.now() + '"`)...

Comment: I'm pretty sure above comment is the answer. I've had the same problem before.

Comment: +1, Thanks War10ck for this answer !